# MIT Scheme: Unspecified return value error

Tags: scheme, fibonacci, mit-scheme

MIT Scheme: I was writing a function to calculate the nth term of the Fibonacci series (section 1.2.2 of SICP) but I am getting the error: Unspecified return value

```
(define (fib n) (
     define (fib-iter a b count) (
            if (= count n) a
            (fib-iter b (+ a b) (+ count 1)))
     (fib-iter 0 1 1))
)
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and kick the "write parentheses as braces in C" habit. Lisps don't have that structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your helper function `fib-iter` is missing a closing bracket at the end, with an extra closing bracket for `fib`. As a result, the line `(fib-iter 0 1 1)` gets included in `fib-iter`, and `fib` ends up containing no expressions to actually evaluate and return, hence the error `... no expression in body ...`.

Here is what you want:

```
(define (fib n)
  (define (fib-iter a b count)
    (if (= count n)
        a
        (fib-iter b (+ a b) (+ count 1))))    ; 1 closing bracket added here
  (fib-iter 0 1 1))                           ; 1 closing bracket removed here
```

You might benefit from using some editors that match parentheses. For example, Dr. Racket highlights the function body that is contained within a set of parens if your cursor is active on either the opening or closing of said parentheses.

Comment: Thank you so much! What I had done was (for me) a conceptual error rather than a syntactical one.
What I was doing:
    (definition of fib (name parameters) (definition of fib-iter and call for fib-iter)) 

But what you have done is:
    (defintion of fib (name parameters) (definition of fib-iter) (call for fib-iter))

Comment: Indeed, notice that `fib-iter` is simply a helper function. Any properly written helper function can be moved out of its parent function, and both should still behave the same (only difference being scope). If you were to move `fib-iter` out of `fib` in your original version, you would have `fib` defined as: `(define (fib n))` with no body expressions to evaluate/return, hence your initial error. Perhaps writing your helper functions on their own would help you conceptualize more what each component is doing.